# Group by week in SAS

Tags: sas

I was writing a `proc tabulate` report, which would summarize data in a table by day and by week.

So far this is what I have:

```
PROC TABULATE
DATA=WORK.FB_REPORT
   ;
   VAR ORDERS UNITS PRICE SERVICE_CHARGE FRUIT_BOUQUET_REV REVENUE;
   CLASS SALES_TYPE /   ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
   CLASS ORDER_DATE /   ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
   TABLE 
          /* By Row*/
          ORDER_DATE *(  Sum={LABEL="Sum"}   )  
          all = 'Total'  *(  Sum={LABEL="Sum"}   )  , /*  CHANGE THIS LINE */
          /* By Column */
          SALES_TYPE *(ORDERS  UNITS  PRICE  SERVICE_CHARGE  MERHCREV  REVENUE REVENUE)
          all = 'Total'  *(MERCHREV  REVENUE REVENUE) ;
   ;

RUN;
```

How can I change the `all = 'Total'*(Sum={LABEL="Sum"})` statement such that, to sum by grouping weeks in `ORDER_DATE`?

Comment: Most straightforward way seems to be: create a variable containing the week and use that for your report. I'm curious whether someone will demonstrate an interesting function that elegantly solves it without the additional data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format to accomplish this.  There are several week-related formats, and if there isn't one you like you can roll your own using a Picture format.  Here's an example using the always-popular WEEKU format:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.citiday;
class date;
var SNYDJCM SNYSECM;
format date WEEKU11.;
tables all date,(snydjcm snysecm)*sum;
run;
```

Date is a variable that contains dates, one row per day, for the entire period of the dataset. (Browse sashelp.citiday for more information.)